# How can I run multiple nodes(Full node, geth client) in single PC in public network?

Tags: full-node, docker, port-numbers

As I know, ethereum network uses 30303 port for UDP/TCP and use 9000 or 8551 for P2P. But, every single public IP has single 30303 port and 8551 port.
Can I run multiple nodes (full, light whatever) in single PC? I'm trying to do this using docker.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how can I do the port binding for each docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Geth allow port configuration using command line parameters.

See the help https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options.

```
geth --discovery.port 30303 --http.port 8545 <..more..parameters..>
```